# Using balanceof function in erc20. i have few questions

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs

Is it the number of tokens i have? or just the balance which i need to somehow convert into number of tokens if it is then how can i convert the balance into number of tokens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of your real balance is the outcome of method `balanceOf` divided by `10 ** decimals()`. Method `decimals()` returns the number of decimals used to get its user representation.

**Example:** If `balanceOf` returns that I have 9000000000000 tokens and the outcome of method `decimals` is 9 then the "display" variant of my tokens would be `9000000000000 / (10 ** 9)` which is 9000 tokens.

If your contract does not have `decimals()` method then "display" variant of your balance is whatever method `balanceOf` returns without any additional calculations.

Comment: and suppose i have 3000 erc20 tokens then  if i want to send only 2.5 tokens how can i send

Comment: Unfortunately solidity does not support floats and this is the reason why method ```decimals()``` exists. If we take the example that the outcome of ```decimals()``` is 9 then if you want to send to your friend 2.5 tokens in his Trust Wallet or MetaMask or any other wallet you will have to send ```25 * (10 ** (decimals() - 1))```.

Comment: Thanks but in some cases in which it got the result in points it changes the token counts it to zero lost the tokens how can i handle it?